# not show image encode from base64_encode

Tags: java, php, android, base64

the below code is in android studio :

```
                Bitmap newImage = (Bitmap) MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver() , data.getData());
                im.setImageBitmap(newImage);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , baos);
                byte[] bytearrayimage = baos.toByteArray();
                String encodeimage = URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeToString(bytearrayimage , Base64.DEFAULT) , "UTF-8");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , String.valueOf(encodeimage.length()) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try
                {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.put("type" , "picprofile");
                    json.put("username" , username);
                    json.put("image" , encodeimage);
                    new ConnectServer().execute("https://estate.shikmelk.ir/api/android/upload.php" , json.toString());
                }
                catch (JSONException j)
                {
                    j.printStackTrace();
                }
```

up section code for create encode image base64 and the below code is in php :

```
    $img = $json["image"];
$imgname = $username . "profile.jpg";
$fopen = fopen("../../main/picprofile/" . $imgname , "wb");
fwrite($fopen , base64_decode($img));
fclose($fopen);
```

up section code is in php and get base64_encode image and convert to jpg image
but when i display the image not show anything meaning convert but not show the image.

Comment: `$img = $json["image"];`. Please post complete php. Nobody knows how you obtained $json. Further nobody knows how you posted the json. So there is little to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytearrayimage, Base64.DEFAULT);` instead of `URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeToString(bytearrayimage , Base64.DEFAULT) , "UTF-8");`

Make sure to import `android.util.Base64`

Comment: i changed it but in php i get null message